# ODE with integrating factor $(3y^2-x)dx + (2y^3-6xy)dy=0, \mu= \phi(x+y^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following problem:

$$(3y^2-x)dx + (2y^3-6xy)dy=0, \mu= \phi(x+y^2)$$

What I did was first checking if the ODE was exact, which is not so I tried to find an integrating factor only dependent either on $x$ or $y$ but there's none. So I get that in order to solve this ODE we need to use the $\mu$ given by the problem. How do you determine an integrating factor dependent on two variables? Is there another approach to this ODE?

Comment: Please check WolframAlpha step-by-step solution.

Comment: What happens when you make the substitution $u=x+y^2$, that is, $x=u-y^2$. Can you find an integrating factor of the transformed equation?

Answer (score 3):

$$(3y^2-x)dx + (2y^3-6xy)dy=0$$
Another approach (substitute $w=y^2$):
$$(3y^2-x)dx + (y^2-3x)dy^2=0$$
$$(3w-x)dx + (w-3x)dw=0$$
$$w'=-\dfrac {(3w-x)}{(w-3x)}$$
It's homogeneous. Substitute $w=tx$. Then it's separable.